# Excel VBA autofilter error

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to make my work easier. I have an worksheet with a pivottable which get its data from a ms sql database (over 100000 records, if that counts). I need to autofilter this data. So I google for it.

I have found this vba code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()

Range("A11").CurrentRegion.AutoFilter field:=6, Criteria1:=Range("d5").Value

End Sub
```

I concluded that I can apply it to my case.

The range which I need to filter starts from A11, the filter should be applied to field no.6 by the value found in cell D5.

At first it does the filtering, but then I get this error:

Method 'Autofilter' of object 'Range' failed

I don't know what is wrong, excel gets stuck and nothing works

Maybe someone could give me a hint or something.

Thank you.

Comment: Record a macro whilst performing the task and see what it gives you. Also, check how you have your data set up e.g. table, pivottable......

Comment: What are the **real** limits of the table ??........ A11 through what ??

Comment: I guess it has something to do with the fact that the datas are setup as a table which gets its data from an external source. I have pasted special the datas in another worksheet and there is no error in this case. I guess I could use this worksheet, with the data I have pasted in.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend trying a fully-defined range for the autofilter, such as:

```
Sub fdsa()
    Dim LR as Long 'LR is last row
    LR = Cells( Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row 'Chose Col D to sort as it's the filter range
    Range("A11:O" & LR).AutoFilter field:=6, Criteria1:=Range("D5").Value 'Arbitrarily chose O as the stop column in the range... adjust as necessary
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try that.